# Как подкючить api к сайту?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

Есть генератор аватарок https://ui-avatars.com/

Они выводятся так:

```
https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=John+Doe
```

Как его подключить к сайту

```
https://мойсайт.com/api/?name=John+Doe
```

Comment: Не понятно, чего вы хотите добиться. API просто выдает фотографию под указанное имя. Вам ее вывести надо?

Comment: Нужно чтобы это работало с моего сайта

Comment: Вот [исходный код](https://github.com/LasseRafn/ui-avatars) этого проекта на gitHub.

Answer (score 1):

```js
void async function() {
  let avatar = await fetch("https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=John+Doe");
  avatar = URL.createObjectURL(await avatar.blob());

  document.querySelector("img").src = avatar;
}();
```

```html
<img>
```

### Что происходит

Отправляем запрос к API при помощи метода `fetch` (скорее всего в продакшн нужен будет полифилл). На выходе получаем ответ с изображением. Дожидаемся получения изображения, конвертируем его в URL, пригодный к использованию в `src` атрибуте, подменяем атрибут. Готово.

Comment: Чет я не пойму зачем весь этот код, если по url и так есть пригодная картинка. Я думал можно полностью перенести весь api к себе не ссылаясь на `https://ui-avatars.com`

Comment: @steep а я не пойму вас. Даже если найдете исходный код этого API, соберете его у себя, захостите, то вам ведь все равно придется делать к этому API запросы. Так в чем смысл?

Comment: @steep API - это по определению публичный интерфейс какого-то приложения. Вам просто предоставляют возможность программно воспользоваться услугами генератора изображений. Зачем что-то куда-то переносить?

Comment: Я понял. Есть что-то подобное на php чтобы установить к себе на сервер?